# Can I setup a PayPal account or Google Checkout account without providing a bank account?

Tags: bank-account, online-payment, paypal

I want to set up an account on PayPal or Google to simplify online transactions.  However, for security reasons, I do not want to link it to a bank account.

I can get a friend to fund the PayPal/Google account and then I can spend the money online (or use the PayPal debit card).

Is this possible?  Can I setup a PayPal or Google Checkout account without giving them a bank account?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes,** you can set up a PayPal or a Google Checkout account without a bank account linked to it.

Neither PayPal nor Google Checkout *requires* you to link to a bank account.

Both services provide for linking your payment account to a **credit card** instead.

Comment: I don't want to use a credit card either.

Comment: @user128807 I suggest you update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but PayPal has limits. Depending on your annual transactions you might have a $$ limit each year unless you agree to tie to a bank account. In my case, I set up another checking account to link to, and keep a small amount there. Less than $200.